# Compile and share in bluej

Tags: javascript, compilation, bluej

Is there a way to compile my code for bluej and share it with a friend without giving them my source code? Only allowing them to run the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export your code into a .jar file, which converts all of your java code into bytecode, which is unreadable by the average person.